# Why is this error appearing: Assets\Character2DController.cs(35,21): error CS0103: The name 'Physics2d' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so for context I'm trying to make the controller of the character, and I'm learning c# so, if you guys have some more tips for te code, please tell
code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Character2DController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 10;
    public float JumpForce;
    bool isGrounded;
    public Transform GroundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
       
    }

     void Update()
    {
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position  += new Vector3 (movement, 0 ,0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (isGrounded)
            {
            _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpForce;
            }
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
       isGrounded = Physics2d.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);

    }
}
```

Comment: It is [`Physics2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) not `Physics2d`.

Answer (score 0):

Unity provides you lots of Physics function APIs for 2D and 3D.

To access the 2D functions use Physics2D static class, not Physics2d.
To access the 3D functions use Physics3D static class, not Physics3d.

Comment: As you have mentioned that you are learning C# and Unity, you can get deep dive into Physics2D static class and all its functions through this youtube link: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrtqd9jHm30NdVww08uuTmergaYOiZZJa

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)